# Mirroring a multi-gpu model across multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, multi-gpu

I have a tensorflow (tf2.0)/keras model that uses multiple GPUs for its computations. There are 2 branches in the model and each branch is on a separate GPU.

I have a 4 GPU system that I want to use for training and I would like to mirror this model so that GPUs 1 and 2 contain one model and GPUs 3 and 4 contain the mirrored model.

Will [tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy)  handle this mirroring automatically? Or does it assume that my model will be a single GPU model?

If `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` will not handle this, does anyone have any suggestions for how to customise `MirroredStrategy` to achieve this training structure?

Comment: This is a Y/N question.

Comment: Run two invocations of your python file, and use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to expose the relevant gpus to each invocation. e.g.; to run the first invocation "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python train_model.py". Mirrored strategy will distribute the training model on available gpus.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like your are gonna need to do a custom training loop.
The mirrored strategy replicates the model on each GPU, but since your model is allready on two GPUs, i don't think that its gonna work properly.

But you can try it out and check with nvidia-smi what tensorflow is doing.